# Missing "key" prop for element in array in nextjs 12.1.0 with react 18?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create a next js app with `npx create-next-app`. But When I am trying to building with running `npm-run-build`. It gives the error. Here next version is 12.1.0 and react version is 18. But When I use same code in next old version like 12.0.10 something like that. Then it gives no error. I thing this is the changes of next js newer version. But What I have do?

The errors like something it-

[image]

Here is index.js code-

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          Get started by editing{' '}
          <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.js</code>
        </p>

        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>Documentation &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p>
          </a>

          <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>Learn &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Examples &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Deploy &rarr;</h2>
            <p>
              Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This code is exactly template code when next app is created. I do nothing change here.

Comment: It's a bug introduced in `eslint-plugin-react` v7.29.0. It has been fixed in [v7.29.1](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/releases/tag/v7.29.1).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is a bug within eslint, other users solved it by downgrading to a previous version (eslint-plugin-react from 7.29.0 to 7.28.0). [github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/3215](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/3215) - or you can just change the config to ignore ESLint on build in your nextjs app - [nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-eslint](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-eslint)